# Why does my game object scale weirdly when its rotation is changed to 0?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, scale

I have a prefab named Spear.

It contains a script like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Hand;
    public float WeaponDamage;
    public Enemy enemyScr;
    public bool IsInHand;

    public void Start()
    {
        enemyScr = GameObject.Find("EvilTriangle").GetComponent<Enemy>();

        Hand = GameObject.Find("Hand");
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        this.transform.position = Hand.transform.position;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Hand").transform;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
        IsInHand = true;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && IsInHand == true)
        {
            this.transform.parent = null;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
            IsInHand = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In play mode, when I click on the spear (and it is vertical in the scene), everything is looking fine.

But when I click on the spear when it is horizontal, (and as you can see in the script, I'm trying to rotate it to 0), its scale is getting weird.

Normal looking spear:
[image]

Weird looking spear:
[image]

This happens every time I drop the spear vertical (while playing), it  gets thinner and thinner.

I have no idea what is causing this problem.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'd bet you have a non-uniform scale applied to the parent object you're placing that object into, or one of its grandparents. See previous Q&A like [Object scales strangely when setting y rotation after parenting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/163768/39518) and [Object scaling when parenting by script](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/102518/39518). Does the advice in these existing threads help solve your problem?

Comment: I don't really know how can I change the non-uniform scale to get this working to be honest

Comment: Make a parent object that has no scale applied. Add a child object for the visual representation you need to change. Apply the scale to the child object, not the parent. Keep any non-uniform scales at the leaf nodes of your hierarchy, never in a parent. I explain this in one of the existing answers I've linked.

Comment: How should I do it? When I set it to 0 the object gets scaled like this too.

Comment: What is the "it" you're setting to zero? I did not suggest setting anything to zero.

Comment: I don't understand how can I make a parent without scale applied, so I set the parent's scale to zero.

Comment: "zero scale" means "please flatten me to a pancake/point" - that's hardly "no scaling". To get a "neutral" scale, **set all three scale axes to 1**, because one multiplied by anything leaves that thing unchanged.

Comment: It works! thanks a lot!